# Double curly braces on SET operation sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have come across the following code:

```
Declare @prmFromDT Datetime;
Declare @prmToDT Datetime;

SET @prmFromDT = '{{ @StartTime }}';
SET @prmToDT = '{{ @EndTime }}';
```

Why the parametres passed on the local variables are around double curly braces?

Comment: Which dbms are you using? That code is product specific.

Comment: Single curly braces are used in T-SQL (SQL Server context) as ODBC escape sequences for Date, Time, and Timestamp data types. Refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/reference/appendixes/date-time-and-timestamp-escape-sequences I am not sure about double curly braces but single curly braces are what I have used

Comment: This is SQL Server @jarlh

Comment: It looks like some placeholder. Can you show us context where this code is used?

Comment: That code by itself generates an error on SQL Server - so there's some more context required here for this code to work. I'm not sure what that context would be. As Incognito notes, single braces are used for ODBC escape sequences but I'm not aware of anything using double braces.

Comment: This is used by Datazen dataview to query an Sql Server db on the given datetimes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the syntax used in your specific program (Datazen Dataview) to substitute parameters.

So what you're seeing are that the SQL variables `@prmFromDT`and `@prmToDT` are being filled with parameters.

Reference:

> In previous versions of Datazen, all parameter substitution was done
>   inline.  This necessitated the use of quotes to wrap string values
>   (ex. WHERE x = '{{ @Xvalue }}'). While this is still the case for
>   non-DB connections types, it is advised not to do so for DB types.
>   While DB types will automatically unwrap the quotes from around a
>   parameter if the parameter is the only text contained within the
>   quotes, if any other text is present, the query will surely fail.  For
>   example, while the above example evaluates to "WHERE x = @p1"
>   something like "WHERE y = 'P001-{{ @Yvalue }}'" will evaluate to
>   "WHERE y = 'P001-@p1'" which is clearly not proper SQL  parameter
>   syntax.

Source:

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/32028.datazen-data-view-parameter-replacement-functions.aspx

Also reference on how to use parameters in datazen and the resulting syntax: 
https://christopherfinlan.com/2015/06/10/how-to-enable-user-activity-reporting-on-your-datazen-dashboards/

Comment: Great. It is the first time I got my hands on Datazen and had no clue